# Is GitHub sources parsed by search engines?

Tags: github

Will Google and other search engines index my source code if I keep them on GitHub?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen any search engine index source code from the major source hosts. Though Google Code Search seems to do it, at some level (and it's going to go the way of the dodo). But if you're putting publicly viewable source code online...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes search for `example site:github.com` in Google.

Answer (score 4):

Access to source code does not appear to be prohibited by GitHub [Robot exclusion policy](https://github.com/robots.txt), so my first guess is that yes, your source code will be indexed.

On the other hand, my attempts at finding my own source code in Google aren't producing any results, so I could be wrong.